# How to Automatically and More Perfectly Center a Text Divider in the TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, horizontal-alignment, pdftex, center

The code

```
 \documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Table of Contents Entry 1}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\vskip 7pt \hskip 135pt \protect\rule{0.85in}{.02mm} \vskip 3pt}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Table of Contents Entry 2}}
\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

I would like to be able to automatically center the text divider in the TOC without having to try to guess how much of an ``hskip'' to impose on it. I tried flanking the `\protect\rule` with two `\hfill`s but that only results in an error.

Question: Can anyone tell me how I may automatically, and more perfectly, center a text divider in   the TOC?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the use of `\hfil` on either side of the `\rule` is sufficient to provide the centering.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Table of Contents Entry 1}}
\addtocontents{toc}{\hfil\protect\rule{0.85in}{.02mm}\hfil\vskip 3pt}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\textbf{Table of Contents Entry 2}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are the contents of the `aux` file

```
\relax 
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\textbf  {Table of Contents Entry 1}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\@writefile{toc}{\hfil \rule {0.85in}{.02mm}\hfil \vskip 3pt}
\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline {section}{\textbf  {Table of Contents Entry 2}}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very helpful answer.